# C# API Get Request with Basic Authentication - Server is Returning (403) Forbidden

Tags: scripting

I'm attempting to make a connection to an API endpoint.  I'm getting (403) Forbidden. I was hoping someone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong with this.  Here's my code:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;                  

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        
 
string token = "Username:Password";
byte[] pwd = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token);
String encodedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(pwd, 0, pwd.Length, Base64FormattingOptions.None);

String PostData = ("Authorization: Basic " + encodedPassword);

    
var myUri = new Uri("http://EndPoint URL");
var myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(myUri);
var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)myWebRequest;
myHttpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedPassword);
myHttpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";

var myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
var responseStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

var myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);
var json = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

responseStream.Close();
myWebResponse.Close();  
    

    }
}
```

Comment: Programming questions should be asked on [so]. If you have problems on the server side, provide the configuration of your server.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that.  I'll post it over there.